# Auto increment primary key with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a table and I want to insert items into it without specifying the `UserID`. I want this ID to be generated automatically.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserMaster] 
(
    [UserID]       INT           NOT NULL ,
    [UserName]     VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [UserPassword] VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [UserRoles]    VARCHAR (500) NULL,
    [UserEmailID]  VARCHAR (100) NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserID] ASC)
);
```

Here I try to insert row via C#:

```
using (LessonesDBEntities context = new LessonesDBEntities())
{
    var u = new UserMaster//Make sure you have a table called UserMaster in DB
    {
        UserName = "test username",
        UserPassword = "test password",
        UserEmailID = "test email",
        UserRoles = "User"
    };

    context.UserMaster.Add(u);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

But I get exception:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__tmp_ms_x__1788CCACDB8355D2'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.UserMaster'. The duplicate key value is (0).
>   The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Use the [`IDENTITY` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Show us your context. Your primary key has no IDENTITY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Make auto-increment at Database level you should include `IDENTITY` in the DDL: `UserID int identity(1,1) not null`

`(1,1)` stands for `UserID` will start at `1` and increment by 1 for each `INSERT`.

Comment: Now I get `Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'UserMaster' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.`

Comment: @Plompy: the `UserId` column in your C# model class needs to be decorated with the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` annotation (see other answer by @RistoM) to make this work

Answer (score 6):

Add `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` attribute to your identity field `UserId`.

```
public class UserMaster
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserPassword { get; set; }

    public string UserEmailID { get; set; }
    public string UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

When your create migration and table based on that model, EF creates identity field with auto increment.

Comment: **AND** the SQL Server table must use `INT IDENTITY(1,1)` for the column `UserId` - this alone doesn't work

Comment: @marc_s ..and my answer also requires, that table is created by EF code first migration.

Comment: and... when you're doing EF code first, the migration file will have something like                     Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false).Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"), etc (Having missed the [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] when I first ran the migration, I ended up having to start from scratch and re-run it. Hopefully just adding the .Annotation part will make someone's life easier.)

Comment: and... the snapshot file will have this:             modelBuilder.Entity("Your_namespace_and_class", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("UserId")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("int")
                        .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:IdentityIncrement", 1)
                        .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:IdentitySeed", 1)
                        .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn); // and more, so re-create the migration, might be safer

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework doesn't know your whole database, it only knows the records you've already fetched into its context. Therefore it cannot determine the maximum used id in the given table.

You have 3 options here:

Use a feature of your db to automatically set the id, an auto-incremented identity column

or

Write a function in your db that returns the max id and set it yourself in EF

or

Get the whole table in your EF (load it completely) and then select the max id.

I strongly advise against option 2 and 3 and for option 1 to use a auto-increment-feature of your database. You should insert them via EF with a id of `null` and the DB will set the id. You need to mark the column accordingly.